# Why is apache2.conf.swp inside /var/tmp more than 6GB?

Tags: apache2, aws, tmp

I recently created my AWS instance with UBUNTU setup. The website is all live and was running fine for a day or so. However after a day when I open, it kept loading for several minutes. So I somehow guessed it's the disk space full.

I used a command and found the culprit was `apache2.conf.swp` inside `/var/tmp` folder. 
[image: cmd generated image]

I wanted to know what is this file `apache2.conf.swp`? Is it safe to delete? How can I prevent it from being created again in future?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! We can only guess...   (and please don't post screenshots of text, you can copy/paste any text). Did you edit the config file for apache? What tool did you use?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old (and hence probably obsolete) question, but I am answering in the hope that it may still help someone in my situation. My /var/tmp/apache2.conf.swp file was 31GB, filling my 40GB root to the brink.

Examining with `file` showed that the `swp` file was created when the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file was edited with `vi` a few days ago.

```
# file apache2.conf.swp

apache2.conf.swp: Vim swap file, version 8.0, pid 2846, user xx, host xxx, file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, modified
```

And since no process with PID `2846` was running currently (nor any other `vi` process), I figured it is safe enough and deleted the file.